# Rails nested form with collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, nested-forms

I have a simple app with three models, Categories, Projects, and Categorizations:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :projects, :through => :categorizations
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :category
end
```

I want to use a single form to create a new Project and associate categories with it.  The portion of the form that passes through data for the Categorization model looks like this:

```
<div class="field">
  <strong>Categories:</strong><br>
    <%= f.fields_for :categorizations do |category| %>
      <%= collection_check_boxes :categorization, :category_ids, @categories, :id, :display_name %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

...and the relevant portions of the controller look like this:

```
def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    @categorizations = @project.categorizations.build(categorization_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save && @categorizations.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def categorization_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:project_ids => [], :category_ids => [])
end
```

When I try to create a new record using this form it successfully creates a new Project record, but the Categorization record does not pass the category_ids through.  When I look at the log it appears to be passing the category_ids as an array of strings:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zt3KGmB20OA28P7Y21QvYjTkJvJg+gQnjOcp//XNB2I=", "project"=>{"slug"=>"new-project-31", "title"=>"New Project 31", "body"=>"Design & research", "published"=>"false"}, "categorization"=>{"category_ids"=>["1", "2", ""]}, "commit"=>"Create Project"}

INSERT INTO "categorizations" ("created_at", "project_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Mon, 03 Mar 2014 00:36:09 UTC +00:00], ["project_id", 27], ["updated_at", Mon, 03 Mar 2014 00:36:09 UTC +00:00]]
```

Any help figuring out how to create individual Categorization records from the form would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very sure whether this will work since you did not show the error message. But I'm guessing that it's because you did not submit the correct parameters to the build method.

Try mapping the array into a hash with something like

...build(categorization_params.map{|cat| cat})

**Edit:**

After discussions:

```
@project.categorizations.build(params[:categorization][:category_id].map{|cat| {category_id: cat}}
```

Comment: I'm actually not getting an error -- it's just creating a single new Categorization record (without any category_ids), rather than creating multiple new Categorization records, one for each submitted category_id.  It looks like it's passing it through the categorization_params as a hash, it's just not using them to create records.

Comment: And for what it's worth, Categorization consists of only project_id and category_id.

Comment: When I add the mapping it then attempts to save @categorizations as an array, but that array is blank ([]).

Comment: You would probably need to map the correct one instead of the categorization_params that has passed through the strong params validation. That is probably the issue.

Comment: I'm not by the com now, but you can probably figure it out through printing params and getting the specific a array to be converted to hash.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "correct one" -- can you explain?

Comment: Print params, then navigate to the specific array via. params[:project][:categorizations][0].map{...}. This is just my best guess though. Else, you can try modifying your categorization_paramsmethod into something like,...require(:project).permit(categorization:...]. Just my best guess.

Comment: If you're still unable to find the array, I'll private message you in about half an hour when I reach my pc

Comment: Still can't get it to work.  I've tried both of the following and neither submits a category_id when the transaction is committed `@categorizations = @project.categorizations.build(categorization_params.map{|category_id| category_id})` and `@categorizations = @project.categorizations.build(categorization_params.merge(:category_id => params[:categorization][:category_id]))`

Comment: Sorry I think I got the syntax for mapping wrong. Can you try: .map{|cat| {categorization: cat}} instead? Also, put params[:project][:categorization] (something like that, essentially it should return your array, ["1","2","3",""].

Comment: Hmm, I can see that it's passing the array `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"fOwFHEc/tXEa03uxTy4+HoaXgJuidKD92Xdg0q7mlII=", "project"=>{"slug"=>"new-project-60", "title"=>"New Project 60", "body"=>"This is the description", "published"=>"false"}, "categorization"=>{"category_id"=>["1", "2", ""]}, "commit"=>"Create Project"}` but I don't know how to tell it to create discrete record for each `param[:categorization][:category_id]`.

Comment: the very crude way should be something like..
@project.categorizations.build(params[:categorization][:category_id].map{|cat| {category_id: cat}}.. I'm not sure if it should be "category_id" though.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Mingsheng, `@project.categorizations.build(params[:categorization][:category_id].map{|cat| {category_id: cat}})` ended up working.  There's probably a simpler way to do it, but this gets the job done.  If you write it up as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Glad it worked. Hopefully someone would chance by and provide a better answer too.